# How to give blue outline to edit text android?

Tags: android

i have an edit text view , i want its border to be of blue color , only its border or outline to be blue  not the complete edit text view .How to get blue border?Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844681/android-custom-edittext-ui Saw this question? Refer the link http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) as a background for the edit text view. You can define it in an xml file in the res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0000ff" />
</shape>
```

If you want to make the background variable depending on whether the edit text view has focus, etc., you can use the above as one element of a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Comment: giving error android:width="1" cannot have integer value & when removed width , its giving black color to my edit text view , i want only outline to be blue not the complete edit text .Above code filing my edit text with black color

Comment: @vaibvorld - Oops. It should be `"1dp"`, not `"1"`. Also, to ensure that the body of the text field isn't black, you can set it to something explicit. I updated the code to fix the width problem and showed how to set the fill color to transparent. You might want white or something theme-based instead. (The black fill problem might even go away without the `android:solid` attribute once the width problem is fixed.)