# how to build the UI for login

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

[image]

I'd like to make my UI similar to this.
Being new to android, I'd like to get some help how I should approach this.

I'm thinking of listView holding 2 rows(email/password) and one footer(Login button).

How would an experienced android developer build this UI?

Comment: Perhaps it could be done with styles

Comment: According to me you should just put a style in and customize the buttons and edittext. A simple google search would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844681/android-custom-edittext-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `RelativeLayout` with a gray background (Color.LTGRAY), or use a 9-patch, textured image. As children views, I would center a title image near the top, and use two `ImageButton`s in an evenly-spaced, centered horizontally, `LinearLayout`. The Login portion would be a `LinearLayout` with a white (Color.WHITE) background, over which I would add an image for each of the line separators. The `EditText`s would have clear (android.R.color.transparent) backgrounds, and the hint would be set to "Email Address" and "Password", respectively. Below would be a clear button with black text displaying "Login".  Finally, a `TextView` between the button and the ImageButtons, centered in the layout, would show the text "or login using".

Comment: how about the border around the login portion?

Comment: You can create an Drawable with stroke color Color.LTGRAY, width to 2, and set rounded edges. This is easiest in XML, but can also be done in code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the XML code you would require. Change it to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/name" 
                android:text="Your company name"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_info" 
            android:text="Login" />

        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow 
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="right" 
                    android:id="@+id/tv_user" 
                    android:text="User" 
                     />

                <EditText  
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:id="@+id/et_user"
                    android:singleLine="true">
                    <requestFocus/>
                </EditText >    
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25" 
                    android:gravity="right" 
                    android:id="@+id/tv_password" 
                    android:text="Password" 
                />

                <EditText  
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:id="@+id/et_password"           
                    android:password="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
             </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_fb" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Facebook"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_twitter" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Twitter"  />            

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_filler" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"           
            android:layout_weight="1"/> 


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: how could you be so fast? is this something you use for one of your apps?

Comment: yes.i also build login ui for my app.