# can be Edittext created by using images? Android

Tags: android, layout

[image]

Hi i hve to create the following edittext, but i do not know how, I have thought that simply add it as a background will help with som padding, but it dont

Comment: What was wrong with adding it as background?

Comment: Possible Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844681/android-custom-edittext-ui, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-a-edittext

Comment: @andrew The padding was awful, it sticked to the bottom, and the resizing was not good to.

Comment: @Csabi you won't be able to support resizing with such type of image without loosing quality or image proportion. The thing you can do here is to make fixed size for `EditText` and adjust all paddings for it, so text can be within whie area only. You can provide different images for different screen size in case you want to make that field bigger on tables etc.

Comment: @andrew Thank you Andrew I have created it, but with android are so many screen size and screen densities, so i think it will be some where it wont be perfect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create xml file in drawable and then apply that xml as background to your edittext.
Example following code will add rounded corners to your edittext

rounded_corners.xml

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#ff6600" >
</stroke>

<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:left="4dp"
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"    >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners
    android:radius="10dp"   >
</corners>

</shape>
```

Then in your layout file apply this xml to editext

```
           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/neworder_route_from"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="From"
                android:padding="10dp" />
```

Comment: But my shape is not as linear as one rounded rectangle. but thanks for your answer